# Quartz.net ADO provider does not refresh jobs and triggers

Tags: c#, refresh, ado, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET version 2.3.x with a database (ADO) provider using SQLServer as the DB engine. The intention is to have one box running as the scheduler processing jobs, and a separate box running a scheduler (not started) that will add/update/remove jobs from the database. The two share the same database settings (below). However, if I start the job-processing scheduler, and then I add a new job+trigger to the database using the second job-manager instance, the job-processing scheduler does not see it. Is there something I need to do to refresh the job-processing scheduler?

Here are the settings I use for the database:

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "BatchTest";
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO";
properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "SERVER=***;...";
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "20";
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you remove the line `properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO";` or set the value to something other than AUTO? (I'm wondering if auto could be generating different ids and treating the schedulers as different).

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm looking at a similar situation.